# Account activation in mobile app

Tags: mobile, iphone, workflow, accounts, payment

I'm designing iphone app which allows users to pay bills. To use this app the user should register and activate their account via e-mail. And here is the problem: Which model I have to choose for the first time use of this app?

1. user register & autologin -> the user can navigate in app but can't do any changes/inputs, can't pay or save data. If the user want to start using this app in full mode he/she must activate an account via e-mail.
2. user register, activate & autologin -> the user can use app in full mode. The difference is that activating the account will be one more step in the registration process.

What do you think? Maybe someone has already done any research about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only question here is whether or not you want unverified users accessing your app.

From a UI perspective, you always want to move the user to the application as fast as possible. All the email confirmation is good for is verifying that you have a human being that you can communicate with at a later point. So in this case, move them along to the app and give them 24 or 48 hours to click the verification link.

If you don't want any-old-person to view your application right away (for security or any other reason) then you should display a message informing the user to "check their email" with instructions on what to do if they can't find the email.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. The only drawback is that the user can't do anything in app without activate his/her account... only switch between nav elements. i thought that will be bit confusing and could be even worse in it's consequnces than simply another step i registration proccess.